# Is it correct to throw OperationCanceledException inside Observable.FromAsync

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have some code similar to

```
observable.Select(x => Observable.FromAsync(token => Task.Run(() =>
{
    // ... do some work ...

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    // ... do some more work ...

    return 7 * x;
}, token)))
.Switch()
.Subscribe(x => 
{
    // Whatever
});
```

The work that happens inside the `Task` can a take a while, so if the `Switch` has moved on to another task (because a new value arrived in `observable`) I want to abort doing that work.

Is the call to `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` the right thing to do? i.e. once the `IObservable` returned from `FromAsync` has been disposed (and canceled the token), will my `OperationCanceledException` be ignored - or will it cause problems somewhere else?

I've tried this out in a test app, and it seems to work ok - but that doesn't mean it's correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underneath the hood, `task.ToObservable()` is eventually called.  `ToObservable` adds a continuation to the task that ends up doing this:

```
switch (task.Status)
{
case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
    subject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
    subject.OnCompleted();
    return;
case TaskStatus.Canceled:
    subject.OnError(new TaskCanceledException(task));
    return;
case TaskStatus.Faulted:
    subject.OnError(task.Exception.InnerException);
    return;
default:
    return;
}
```

Which would mean the observable would fail with the `TaskCanceledException`.  But in your code by the time this happens there are no observers observing the `AsyncSubject` so nothing happens.  So it seems OK.